# Javascript console.log Loads Prematurely

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am working with Ian Li's [Raphael SketchPad](http://ianli.com/sketchpad/), and am having some trouble saving a drawing.

Upon changes on my `sketchpad` an object with id `data` is supposed to get updated, I placed a console log "changed" just to check. What happens is that upon loading the screen I see the console log message, and I don't see it again when changes are made.

How do I make the console.log run only after changes are made?
Here is the extended code for the template I am using:
https://gist.github.com/benbakhshi/5143484

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var sketchpad = Raphael.sketchpad("editor", {
      height: 260,
      width: 260,
      editing: true // true is default
   });

   // When the sketchpad changes, update the input field.
   sketchpad.change(function() {
      $("#data").val(sketchpad.json());
      console.log("changed");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact (not broken) code ?

Comment: You have errors in your javascript.

Comment: OP, even after the edit the code is broken.

Comment: Was missing the closing ">". What other errors are there? Not my browser nor my IDE show me errors.

Comment: You're at least missing `})` at end of the script. You don't have matching braces, this can't compile.

Comment: Can you add the code doing the changes to the sketchpad ? There isn't enough code here to see the problem.

Comment: Ok, fixed the broken code, I think. (I forgot to paste over the closing brackets.)

Comment: Added a link to more of the code.

Comment: is your #data element updating or not? This code is almost identical to the reference example, I'm struggling to see what could be interfering, assuming you have divs with id "editor" and "data"...

Comment: in your gist you have `input #data`, but no element with id "data" inside an input element.

Comment: Benjamin, you may find this useful http://jshint.com/ (also a Node module `npm install -g jshint`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks like you're trying to `console.log` without a guarantee that the `.json` call has actually finished. Instead, try hooking to the `change` event of `#Data` to perform the logging. This will **guarantee** that the `.json` call has finished before logging.

Something like:

```
var sketchpad = Raphael.sketchpad("editor", {
  height: 260,
  width: 260,
  editing: true // true is default
});

$("#data").change(function () {
    console.log("changed");
});

// When the sketchpad changes, update the input field.
sketchpad.change(function() {
  $("#data").val(sketchpad.json()).change();
});
```

Comment: How exactly do you think async operations work in javascript? If `sketchpad.json()` were async, it would need to return a promise (which I guarantee, `.val()` is not equipped to deal with) or receive a callback (we can see it doesn't).

Comment: That still didn't fix my issue. What I found strange is source code says to run `sketchpad.change(function() {
  $("#data").val(sketchpad.json());
 });` although the input whose value is being updated has no ID, only name.  I have tested my input with name,id & class, with #data & .data, together, and separately, but no results.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin `.val()` can receive a callback, just not an asynchronous one :)

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi see my comment on your question, remove the space between `input` and `#data` or just use `#data` on its own.

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi Did you try `$("[name='data']")`?

Comment: @mattytommo, yes. No luck.

Comment: @Ian, that doesn't make a lot of sense. Assuming we are talking about the same function, `.val()` can receive a value (when I say receive, I am always referring to function params), if it received a callback (i.e., a function) it would probably just call `toString` on it, or error out. Which is still all irrelevant, because `sketchpad.json` would need to receive the callback, (which it clearly doesn't, having an empty param list), *not* `.val`.


@BenjaminBakhshi, are you seeing any errors on the console? Have you tried removing all the other code to try and just get the change working?

Comment: @DavidMcMullin `val` can receive a callback, see the overload that takes a function here http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @DavidMcMullin Sure it makes sense. http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value

Comment: @mattytommo , that's actually pretty cool, thanks for pointing it out. But it's still fairly irrelevant - the console.log is definitely executing after the call to `sketchpad.json()`.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin It's relevant for the fact that I mentioned that `.val()` accepts a callback, just not an async (deferred) one, meaning it requires a `return` statement

Comment: @Ian, Yes, you were absolutely correct, but this answer still doesn't solve the problem, and IMO introduces some confusion...

Comment: @DavidMcMullin Haha you're probably right about the answer, I have no idea what the `.json()` call does. I was just trying to point out the `val` "callback" availability. I think your original suggestion to use `$("#data")` (`$("input#data")`) is a possible solution, nonetheless correct